# Syntax error on token ";", ,expected

Tags: listview, syntax

I am trying to make simple list view as follows. I am keep getting syntax error. Could you help me on this? Thanks in advance. What is the cause?

```
public class BlockListViewActivity extends Activity {


    Button previousButton;
    Button addButton;
    Button deleteButton;

    ArrayList<String> Items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
    ListView listview1;            // Syntax error ";", ,expected

    Items = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blocklist);

        Items = new ArrayList<String>();

        Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, Items);


        previousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousButton);

        addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        deleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

        listview1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.blockListView);

        listview1.setAdapter(Adapter);
        listview1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the next line `Items = new ArrayList<String>();`. Add a variable name there and the syntax error goes away. The compiler simply fails to realize just what the error was.